Apply a tint mask to a texture with specific parameters from Unreal Engine 5
I've got an ARGB tint mask which applies to a base color texture with some UE5 script which uses parameters from pic1 which I can't quite understand.
How do I approach it with blender shader nodes?




What is it doing? I see just pictures thrown without a clear goal.

So you have 4 channels (R,G,B, Alpha) from third picture (tint mask), then first picture sets parameters on how to apply each channel from the tint mask to the texture (second picture). That's how I see it
